# Batch File to add random string to registry

Tags: random, batch-file, registry

I am trying to make a batch file that will create a random four digit number (eg. 8472) and then edit a registry string with this number.

Here is where I am and it's not working. As you can see there is already a string in the registry I need this script to change the last four digits each time it is run. Where am I going wrong? Also pause is not working my cmd windows close as fast as they open.

```
echo -----------------------------------
echo --------------Testing--------------
echo -----------------------------------

:beg
set rnd %random%
if %rnd% GTR 9999 goto beg
if %rnd% LSS 1111 goto beg

REGEDIT4
; @ECHO OFF
; CLS
; REGEDIT.EXE /S "%~f0"
; EXIT

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Test]
"Test"="{12345678-12A1-123B-A12C-123A123B%rnd%}"
```

Comment: I'd really like to know why you are doing this?  Just out of curiousity.

Answer (score 1):

```
set /A RND=%RANDOM% %% 8889 + 1111
reg add HKLM\Software\Test /v Test /T REG_SZ /d "{12345678-12A1-123B-A12C-123A123B%RND%}" /f
```

Should do the trick.  Note the doubled `%%` mod operator for use in a batch file; if you do this from a command prompt, only use one `%`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think regedit knows how to read input data from the batch file it's run from. You might have to create a temporary file, something like this (untested):

```
echo [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Test] >tmp.reg
echo "Test"="{12345678-12A1-123B-A12C-123A123B%rnd%}" >>tmp.reg
start /wait regedit4 tmp.reg
erase tmp.reg
```

The `start /wait` will cause the batch file to wait until `regedit4` has finished before deleting the `tmp.reg` file.

Also, if your windows are closing right away, then open a "command prompt" window and run your batch file from there instead (I suppose you are currently clicking on a shortcut to your batch file).

Comment: That is what I'm doing I will go test this

Comment: As far as getting that string into the Registry that is working but still if I put the random number generator above it, then it wont work.

Comment: Do you need an `=` between `rnd` and `%random%`?

Comment: also that .reg file wont import into the registry

Comment: Ok. I'm afraid I don't have a Windows machine handy to test this, I was just going from memory.

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition. We can extract characters from the right side of a string using the syntax    `%RANDOM:~-N%` where *N* is the number of requested digits.  To create a 4-digit-random-number use:

```
> echo %RANDOM:~-4%
```

But since this only works when the number is >999:

```
> set var=0%RANDOM%
> echo %var:~-4%
```

So another way to do it is:

```
> set /A var=%RANDOM% + 1000
> echo %var:~-4%
```

Since `RANDOM` is a random variable from 0 to 32767 let's check for overflows:

```
> set /A var=32767 + 1000
33767
```

Hope this helps.